# Stand-alone dialogue/conversation engine?

Tags: game-engine

As part of a game I am developing I require a rather robust dialogue/quest engine to handle character interactions. To my knowledge, no such engine exists separate from the few far more general game engines that include dialogue as part of their predefined game structure.

I'm not asking for anything integrated with an existing engine, nor do I expect that such an engine would be a simple drag-and-drop process to integrate with my game. If such an engine does not exist, I plan to build one myself. I just thought I'd ask if anyone had seen something I'd missed while searching to save myself the time.

To be clear, I am looking for a dialogue engine separate from any game engine. I understand they are often seen as one and the same.

Comment: Really interesting idea. If you decide to make a dialoge engine yourself, plese let us know :)